# Throwing a class between subsequent elements

Tags: jquery, selector

I've generated a set of DIVs like this.

```
<div id="donkey1" class="target"></donkey>
<div id="donkey2" class="target"></donkey>
<div id="donkey3" class="target"></donkey>
```

Then I set a class on the first one and try then to propagate it to the next one like this.

```
$("#donkey1").addClass("active");
...
$("#donkey1").on("keyDown", function() {
  .removeClass("active")
  .getNextTag().addClass("active");
});
```

My problem is that I'd like the propagating to be done generically on **any** DIV (of a certain class, of course) and I can't get a hit on the implementation of *getNextTag* method.

I'd start like this (still not getting to the implementation, though).

```
$("#donkey1").addClass("active");
...
$(".target").on("keyDown", function() {
  .removeClass("active")
  .getNextTag().addClass("active");
});
```

How can one implement the "get the DIV next to this one"?

Note that I prefer **not** to make use of the index. It's just there because I lack imagination. The actual ids will most likely be very irregular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you just use jQuery's [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) operator?

> Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of
>   matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next
>   sibling only if it matches that selector.

You can add a selector in it, like `next(".target")`

Comment: Why can't I? Because I didn't know about it, hehe. I've done this long time ago and forgot how I did. Thanks!

Comment: @KonradViltersten Yeah that comment was a bit aggressive on my part lol sorry! Glad it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to try this way:

```
$(".target").on("keyDown", function() {
  //assuming you want to remove on the current element.
  $(this).removeClass("active").next().addClass("active");
  //Just on the safer side if you have other siblings which are not `.target` use a selector in .next()
   $(this).removeClass("active").next('.target').addClass("active");
});
```

use **[.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)** to get to the next div and `.target` to select the target and `$(this)` for the current element in action.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re selecting an element with jQuery and want to do something to the next element then you can use the aptly-named `next()` method:

```
$('.target').on('keyDown', function() {
    $('.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
}
```

Be careful when you get the last element though; you’ll need to put some sort of check in for this case.

Comment: Is there a neat jQuery approach to such a protector for *next* and *prev* or should I use *if*?